# Android changing order of items run-time in Realm Recyclerview

Tags: realm, android-recyclerview

I need to order the list of items based on a field say `starredAt`

I am loading the data in the recyclerview from Realm DB using RealmRecyclerView by thorbenprimke

The field changes it value on user's action i.e when user presses star button the item should be moved to top.

For this I am just updating the `starredAt` field of the object.

The items are already sorted by `starredAt` so realm loads the updated list but it randomly adds one more item to the recyclerview.

CheatSheet.java

```
public class CheatSheet extends RealmObject {

@PrimaryKey
private String id;

private RealmList<Item> items;

private String title;

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public RealmList<Item> getItems() {
    return items;
}

public void setItems(RealmList<Item> items) {
    this.items = items;
}
}
```

Item.java

```
public class Item extends RealmObject {

@PrimaryKey
private String id;

private String description;

private Date starredAt;

public Item() {
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public Date getStarredAt() {
    return starredAt;
}

public void setStarredAt(Date starredAt) {
    this.starredAt = starredAt;
}
}
```

CheatSheetActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

RealmRecyclerView revItems;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setData();
}

private void setData() {
    rvItems = (RealmRecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rev_items);
    RealmResults<Item> items = Realm.getDefaultInstance().where(CheatSheet.class)
                      .equalTo("id", "some-id").findFirst().getItems()
                      .where()
                      .findAllSorted("starredAt", Sort.DESCENDING);

    ItemRealmListAdapter itemRealmListAdapter = 
                  new ItemRealmListAdapter(this, items, 
                                           true, true);
    rvItems.setAdapter(itemRealmListAdapter);
}
```

ItemRealmListAdapter.java

```
public class ItemRealmListAdapter extends RealmBasedRecyclerViewAdapter<Item,
    ItemRealmListAdapter.ItemViewHolder> {

RealmResults<Item> mItems;

public ItemRealmListAdapter(Context context, RealmResults<Item> realmResults,
                            boolean automaticUpdate, boolean animateResults) {
    super(context, realmResults, automaticUpdate, animateResults);
    this.mItems = realmResults;
}

@Override
public ItemViewHolder onCreateRealmViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    return new ItemViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.item_layout_cs_text, viewGroup, false));
}

public Item getItem(int position) {
    return mItems.get(position);
}

@Override
public void onBindRealmViewHolder(ItemViewHolder itemViewHolder, int position) {
    itemViewHolder.txtBody.setText(getItem(position).getDescription());
    if (getItem(position).getStarredAt() != null) {
        itemViewHolder.imvStar.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_star_yellow);
    }
    itemViewHolder.imvStar.setOnClickListener(v -> handleStarClick(v,position));
}

private void handleStarClick(View v, int position) {
    if (getItem(position).getStarredAt() != null) {
        ((ImageView) v).setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_star);
        CheatSheetStorage.unStarItem("some-id", getItem(position));
    } else {
        ((ImageView) v).setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_star_yellow);
        CheatSheetStorage.starItem("some-id", getItem(position));
    }

}

public static class ItemViewHolder extends RealmViewHolder {

    @Bind(R.id.txt_cheat_sheet)
    TextView txtBody;

    @Bind(R.id.img_star)
    ImageView imvStar;


    public ItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
    }
}
}
```

CheatSheetStorage.java

```
public class CheatSheetStorage {
 public static void unStarItem(String cheatSheetId, Item item) {
    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    realm.beginTransaction();
    CheatSheet cheatSheet = getCheatSheetById(cheatSheetId);
    Item itemDB = cheatSheet.getItems().where().equalTo("id", item.getId()).findFirst();
    itemDB.setStarredAt(null);
    realm.commitTransaction();
}

public static void starItem(String cheatSheetId, Item item) {
    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    realm.beginTransaction();
    CheatSheet cheatSheet = getCheatSheetById(cheatSheetId);
    Item itemDB = cheatSheet.getItems().where().equalTo("id", item.getId()).findFirst();
    itemDB.setStarredAt(new Date());
    realm.commitTransaction();
}
}
```

Please refer following screenshots for clearer idea :

[Screenshot before starring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKfkH.jpg)

[Screenshot after starring the sixth item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OnUkF.jpg)

Comment: Sounds like something is not being recycled/rebound properly? But please show some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Rohan-Peshkar - You will have to provide a `animateExtraColumnName` value to the adapter. For the animations, the adapter keeps track of the items and since that item's id doesn't change, the list isn't updated. With an additional column (in your case that should be the `starredAt` column - as long as it is stored as an `Integer`), the diffing algorithm will detect a change and the order is updated.

For reference: https://github.com/thorbenprimke/realm-recyclerview/blob/2835a543dce20993d8f98a4f773fa0e67132ce52/library/src/main/java/io/realm/RealmBasedRecyclerViewAdapter.java#L177

You can also check out the `MainActivity` in the example folder. The example changes a row's text from "ABC" to "Updated ABC" and the list recognizes the change because both the primary key and the quote field are used to basically create a composite key for diffing purposes.

Comment: Sorry for replying too late, actually the field `starredAt` is type of date and I need to sort on the basis of date itself. This field is updated on user action.
And while sending the real results I am querying them in sorted order itself

Comment: Okay. Sounds like for your case, @RohanPeshkar , support for Date as an `animateExtraColumnName` has to be added. 
For the time being, if you turn off row animations, it should work as expected in regards to the list updating. It just won't have the nice RecyclerView animations.

Comment: Support for Date has been added. upgrade the lib to `0.9.21` (https://github.com/thorbenprimke/realm-recyclerview/commit/295895fa49a8499aa4b5fe2c0658573411ada781). Give that a try. The example has been updated to use `Date` as well.

Comment: Thanks Thorben will try this

Comment: Let me know and if it works, could you accept this as the answer? Thanks!